# 3d Cube to show 3 sides at a time

Tags: css, 3d, css-transitions, css-animations

I've been looking at different tutorials to make a rotating 3d cube in CSS3. This tutorial from [the-art-of-the-web](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/3d-transforms/) is the one that I've decided to leverage.

My end goal is to have it look similar to this:

[image: 3d Cube on corner]

I want the final state to show 3 sides of the cube. I'd probably also need to rotate the entire cube so the bottom corner between `A` and `T` is pointing down.

[Working fiddle (`-webkit`)](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/n573C/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes spincube {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    to {
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg) rotateZ(15deg); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/a7z6R/1/)**

```
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

This Way You Can Preserve Animation State.

Comment: I didn't know about `animation-fill-mode`. Here is a link to the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode